# How to make a discord bot be able to play youtube audio more than once (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make my bot play music more than once (after a track finishes), but right now it can only play through one time then stops.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def play(ctx, url):
    author = ctx.message.author
    voice_channel = author.voice_channel
    vc = await bot.join_voice_channel(voice_channel)
    player = await vc.create_ytdl_player(url)
    player.start()
```

Comment: can't you call `player.start()` again?

Comment: it seems to me that there wouldnt be a logical place to put it and have it working...

Comment: just copy and paste it below and see if it plays 2 times, then you can just use a loop to play it N number of times